# Calculate amount using SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server. I have imported Excel file sheet into SQL server. In this table I have three column fields like this:

```
AMount    Name              Type
277.6    Arasu              Tax
119.23   Karthi             Tax
446.43   Selvam             Tax
381.63   Alex               Tax
119.23   Karthi             income
446.43   Selvam             income
381.63   Alex               income
```

Now I want to calculate amount based type value. How to calculate separate amount tax type and income type? How can I get separately tax and income amount?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
SELECT SUM(Amount), Type
FROM yourTableNameHere
GROUP BY Type
```

Is that what you're asking?

Comment: Cool. Glad that worked for you. Be sure to mark as the answer.

Comment: That's too chatty

Answer (score 0):

Do you meant something like this?:

```
select A.Name, A.AMount as TAX_Amount, B.AMount as Income_Amount
from yourTable A left join yourTable B
    on A.Name = B.Name
where A.Type = 'Tax'
    and B.Type = 'income'
order by A.Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sum of TAX and INCOME separate with:

```
select sum(AMount),Type from taxincome group by Type;
```

(taxincome is what I called the table).

Comment: I think this is the same answer that @pmbAustin post

Comment: Yes it is, I noticed once I had posted my answer that Sami had as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
;WITH cte(AMount,Name,Type)
AS
(
SELECT 277.6  ,'Arasu'  ,'Tax'      Union All
SELECT 119.23 ,'Karthi' ,'Tax'      Union All
SELECT 446.43 ,'Selvam' ,'Tax'      Union All
SELECT 381.63 ,'Alex'   ,'Tax'      Union All
SELECT 119.23 ,'Karthi' ,'income'   Union All
SELECT 446.43 ,'Selvam' ,'income'   Union All
SELECT 381.63 ,'Alex'   ,'income'   
)
SELECT * ,SUM(AMount)OVER(Partition by Type)TotalIncome_TaxAmount From
(
SELECT Name,Type,SUM(AMount)AMount FROM cte
GROUP BY Name,Type
)Dt
```